# If you have an employee and taxes are greater than $2500, you have to file electronically?

Tags: united-states, taxes, electronic-filing

My reading of the IRS's tax instructions is that if a family has an employee like a maid or cook, and that employee generates more than $2500 per quarter in taxes, then the family has to file electronically. Is that right?

It seems kind of onerous to force people to file monthly/electronically just because they have a cook.

If a person is computer illiterate, then what? They have to hire an accountant or tax preparer, just because they have a cook? Seems kind of unreasonable.

Comment: Can you add a reference to where you read that?

Comment: If you can do your own taxes you can probably also figure out payroll and income taxes for your household employee. You would also need to do so for your state withholdings unless you are in a state without income taxes (TX, etc.). If the amounts are not too high, just over-withhold on your personal income taxes a bit. For IRS see Pub 926. What state are you in? Look for the household employers guide for your state, e.g., DE 8829 for California.

Answer (score 1):

Federally, there doesn't seem to be a requirement, at least as far as I can tell; in [Publication 926](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p926#en_US_2020_publink100086765 they state:

> You’re not required to withhold federal income tax from wages you pay a household employee. You should withhold federal income tax only if your household employee asks you to withhold it and you agree. The employee must give you a completed Form W-4.

For employees *in general*, the requirement to submit taxes withheld is indeed at a minimum of $2500 per quarter, per [Publication 15-T](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p15.pdf); that indicates that you must pay via EFT (EFTPS, specifically, in most cases); but household employees don't have the withholding requirement.

Massachusetts taxes would work the same way.
According to the [Massachusetts Household Employer Tax guide](https://www.mass.gov/guides/tax-guide-for-household-employers#-state-responsibilities-):

> State income tax withholding is not required for a household employee, but may be paid if the employee requests it and you agree.

and

> Employers withholding $5,000 or more have to file returns and make payments electronically.

You do so by paying at [Mass Tax Connect](https://mtc.dor.state.ma.us/mtc/_/), which also has links as to how to file.

It seems like a rare case that a single household employer would need to withhold that much; you'd have to have several household employees to have that much required withholding. In the case that you can afford well over $100k in household employee salaries, you're not going to get much sympathy from me or anyone else if you also have to hire a tax accountant (and probably you should do that for other reasons in any event, at that income/wealth level).

Comment: The question involves US federal taxes

Comment: @FiveBagger Rather than making us guess, please link to where you read what you are talking about, so that we can respond with an explanation.